# Karate test framework: contains only with multiline JSON

Tags: karate

I'm using Karate test framework.

This feature is working:

```
Given path '/endpoint'
When method GET
Then match response.list contains only { "field1": "value1", "field2": "value2"}
```

But I don't want to write the whole JSON in a single line, so I tried:

```
Given path '/endpoint'
When method GET
Then match response.list contains only
"""
{
  "field1": "value1",
  "field2": "value2"
}
"""
```

I'm getting this error:

```
 Tests in error: 
  example.feature:11 - more than one step-definition method matched: match response.list contains only - [public void com.intuit.karate.StepActions.matchDocstring(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String) [response.list contains , only], public void com.intuit.karate.StepActions.match(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String) [response.list , contains,  only]]
```

Is there any way to use contains only and also use multiline JSONs? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes this is a parser edge case, just split into 2 steps:

```
Given def response = { list: { "field1": "value1", "field2": "value2" } }
And def expected =
"""
{ "field1": "value1", "field2": "value2"}
"""
Then match response.list contains only expected
```

Please note that `contains only` makes sense only for JSON arrays, think about it please.

Comment: I accept the answer, but also I think that the fix looks a lot like a workaround. It makes a lot of sense writing a compiler that supports for "contains only" the same arguments than other similar operations like ==.

Comment: @italktothewind karate is open source, kindly contribute a fix :)